# Laravel Redis Error - Cannot use SAVE with a cluster of connections

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I am new in **Redis**. Is anyone know, why these error showing?
I am using **Laravel**.

- Cannot use SAVE with a cluster of connections
- Cannot use FLUSHDB with a cluster of connections

  $redis = Redis::connection();

  $redis->set('name', 'Harry');

  echo $name = $redis->get('name'); //It is working fine

  $redis->save();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

www/projectname/app/config/database.php

Find,

```
'redis' => array(
       'cluster' => false,
       'default' => array(
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        )
 );
```

If ‘cluster’ is true, make it false. May be your issue will solve.

Comment: Thanks. You save lots of time.